# Proving $E[AB|B] = BE[A|B]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $A$ and $B$ be two discrete random variables. Show that
$$E[AB|B] = BE[A|B]$$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
E[AB|B] &= \sum_a\sum_b abP(AB=ab|B=b)\\
&= \sum_a \sum_b abP(A=a|B=b)\\
&= \sum_b b\sum_a aP(A=a|B=b)\\
&= \sum_b bE[A|B]\\
&= BE[A|B]
\end{align*}
So in the first to second equality I'm stating that $P(AB=ab|B=b) = P(A=a|B=b)$. Is this valid? And the jump I make from the second last to last equality I'm also unsure about.

Comment: Cudos on using MathJax! Re question itself: which definition of conditional expectation were you given?

Comment: Why do you have a sum over $b$?

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you could start with letting $$g(b)= \mathbb E[AB \mid B=b] = \mathbb E[Ab \mid B=b] =b\,\mathbb E[A \mid B=b]$$ and then saying $$\mathbb E[AB \mid B] = g(B) = B\,\mathbb E[A \mid B]$$

This does not need your discrete distribution or sumation, but if you want you can say $g(b)= \sum\limits_a ab\, \mathbb P(A=a  \mid B=b)= b\sum\limits_a a\, \mathbb P(A=a  \mid B=b)=b\,\mathbb E[A \mid B=b]$ and so $g(B)=B\sum\limits_a a \mathbb P(A=a  \mid B) = B\mathbb E[A \mid B]$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the expectation is written in terms of the conditional distribution:

$$\mathbb E [AB \mid B] = \sum_a a  \mathbb P(A = a| B )$$

Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Good point, no it wasnt :)

Comment: I'm confused, why don't we sum over $b$ and why, given your equation, would it not be $\sum_a abP(A=a|B)$? Is it because $P(AB|B) = P(A|B)$?

Comment: That's the definition of expectation. On the lefthandside we're saying: compute the expectation of $AB$ with respect to the distribution of $A$ given that $B$ is constant. Recall the expectation is a weighted sum of the values a random variable can take, weighted by the probability at that point. So in your problem, we sum over all possible values of $A$ and compute a weighted sum. $B$ is treated as constant here (since we condition on it) so we do not sum over it's values